# unable to create table with column name e.test2

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi All required some help,

Is it possible to create table with column name e.test? Because i'm hitting error 
`ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
SQL state: 42601`
Example as below

```
create table test(e.test2 int)
```

Comment: Yes because the '.' is a special character

Comment: Dot is reserved as a character for separating database from table from column name.  If you really have a database or table named `e` then feel free to use this name, otherwise drop it.

Comment: If you want to organize your table in more complex way then just a plain list of columns then consider a [Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html)

Comment: How about using space for column name?

Comment: Use `@<user>` to address your comment to the specific person (@Aiman for example). Is there any reasons why you don't want to use a normal identifiers for the columns names? However something like `create table "Είναι υπέροχο τραπέζι μου" ("Είναι γλυκιά η στήλη μου" int);` will work. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some additions to Gordon's answer:

Never ever use special chars except an underscore in a table name or column name. There are several reasons to avoid a dot in a table or column name.

The dot is a reserved character in SQL syntax to express qualified names in the from of *database.table.column*

You might want to use your DB in some Application that consists of several "layers". Odds are very high that you run into trouble with dots in a table or column name in at least one of the other layers.

I.e. Hibenate uses the dot as a separator. From the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/):

> The @FieldResult name is composed of the property name for the
>   relationship, followed by a dot ("."), followed by the name or the
>   field or property of the primary key.

If you want to use the database in a C, C++ or Java application: These languages don't allow dots in class or class member (field) names (the dot is also used here as a separator).

Hence you will have to translate names forth and back between database and application.

Last not least: Joins. Imagine one of the columns in the example below would contain a dot (i.e. fir.stname). I haven't tried this ever, but I bet your DB will choke on that. Besides that, it's confusing.

```
SELECT person.firstname, person.lastname, address.city
FROM from person
INNER JOIN address
ON person.id = address.person;
```

**TL;DR** You can get around these problems, if you translate your table/column fields forth and back and use quotation. But you can spare yourself a lot of pitfalls an hassles if just you just use english alphabetic characters and underscores in table / column names.

> How about using space for column name?

I wouldn't do that neither. I would use an underscore instead of a space.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I do not advise that you name a column with a period in it.  Seriously consider using an underscore instead:

```
create table test(e_test2 int)
```

Having special characters in a column is just a pain.

If you want to learn why it is a bad idea, use double quotes:

```
create table test("e.test2" int)
```

You will have to use double quotes whenever you reference the column.